# How to know Method ID of a code

Tags: solidity

PLease, how do I get the method ID of this code?:

```
function bulkExcludeFee(address[] memory accounts, bool state) external onlyOwner {
    for (uint256 i = 0; i < accounts.length; i++) {
        _isExcludedFromFee[accounts[i]] = state;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the function signature, it would be hex 8e2839ff, calculated as the first 4 bytes of keccak256("bulkExcludeFee(address[],bool)")